# Как сделать готовое исполняемое приложение с библиотеками Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator, сборка

Всем привет. В Qt Creator (работаю на Linux Ubuntu) собрал из исходников релизное приложение, модули: core, gui, xml, network. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было спокойно запаковать приложение в архив и скинуть на другую систему? Читал про динамическую / статическую линковку, но не совсем понял как это осуществить, тем более в Linux'e. Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, просто Linux и QtCreator для меня в новинку.

Или хотя бы подскажите куда копать, если не трудно.

Qt собирал сам из исходников, версия 4.8.7

Comment: Теперь заново собирайте исходники qt с флагом `-static`.

Comment: Вам нужна статья, как делать в линуксе deploy для Qt4, но в интернете этого уже наверное не найти. Нужно паковать саму программу и выясните с помощью ldd, какие shared object библиотеки из ваших собранных она тянет, их тоже надо паковать.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно достаточно указать пути до lib в LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/QT-5.9.7/5.9.7/lib/:.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте, что лицензия LGPL запрещает статическую линковку с не свободынм ПО (вы же прочитали лицензионное соглашение?).
Qt действительно для этого нужно пересобрать - [вот примерная инструкция](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/qt_static)
Только вместо

```
make install
```

лучше установить пакет [checkinstall](https://habr.com/ru/post/130868/) и выполнить

```
checkinstall
```

Еще лучшим вариантом для вас будет использование не самосборной Qt, а скачанного пакета, сборка программы и копирование файлов, необходимых для её работы.

Comment: Не запрещает LGPL компоновку со статическими библиотеками, просто в этом случае нужно предоставлять доступ к объектным файлам.